# How to create UIButtons anchored to the bottom of the view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

What's the best practice to create a few UIButtons in code that are anchored to the bottom of the view with a predefined spacing between each?

Answer (score 1):

Use the buttons' `autoresizingMask` property. If the parent view's only going to resize vertically, then that can just be set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`.